# JavaFX freezes when the system date/time changed to a day/time in the past

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

I have a strange problem. I starting my JavaFX program, that draws objects (rectangles, circles and etc.) on the screen using commands sent through a socket. When changing the system clock backwards (e.g. at 11:00 it changes at 9:00), JavaFX does not shows the result (i.e. created object) of executed commands, and the program logic in the background works and prints messages in the console for a received and executed command, but nothing is displayed on the screen.
The time is changed by command:

```
sudo date --set 'time' && sudo hwclock --systohc
```

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with kernel release version 3.4.39-s5p4418. This OS works on Smart4418 module.

`uname -a` output:

> Linux 4418Module 3.4.39-s5p4418 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 18 14:06:20 HKT 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

Java version:

> java version "1.8.0_171"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

I use JavaFX Embedded SDK is downloaded from [Gluon's website](http://nexus.gluonhq.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/javafxports/armv6hf-sdk/8.60.11/).

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable explanation, other than something weird with the code. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, of course @Itai! I uploaded the code to this link - https://pastebin.com/FjcR2qSj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monocle.java in jfxrt.jar uses java/util/Timer.java(JDK1.8) to manage the screen.

Method "MainLoop" in TimerThread(JDK1.8) computes time of execution using the "systemtime".

If the "systemtime" goes backward, this TimerThread freezes.

I fixed it by modifying Monocle.java to call a modified Timer.java, and updating them in jfxrt.jar

Comment: Can you share your solution, @user10384350?

Comment: I have exact same problem. Background logic (even pressing UI buttons) is running but nothing changes on screen. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: If anyone else runs into this problem, please note that MonocleTimer.java has been updated in newer releases of JavaFX to workaround the Timer issue. Here is the corresponding bug report. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8176499

Comment: Thanks @DavidTaylor! The problem is solved by using the changes from the link you shared.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time searching solution I have found one (I had problem on Raspbian Strech/Buster on RPi3, on Windows 10 everything is working fine). I added "fake" animation to one of my component (which can be hidden) and now UI does not freeze when changing system time. It is only workaround until I find better solution.

```
final Rotate fakeRotate = new Rotate();
    backButton.getTransforms().add(fakeRotate);

    fakeAnimation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.hours(24),
                    new KeyValue(
                            fakeRotate.angleProperty(),
                            0.1,
                            Interpolator.LINEAR
                    )
            )
    );

    fakeAnimation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    fakeAnimation.play();
```